# iOS 9 - open resource in web browser on another computer, triggered by tablet

Tags: ios, rest, mobile, cross-platform

If you had to open a resource from a database in a web browser on another computer, using an Apple tablet app as a remote control, how would you implement such a feature? This is basically what WhatsApp Web does, so it should be technically possible. But how would you go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you mean a situation where the app modifies something on the server, and the browser then updates automatically to reflect this. If you mean something like the iOS Remote app, then you may have to use another method (and you may not be able to do it from the browser).

To do this you'll have to have a server that both the iOS app and the browser are connected to. When the app does something, it updates the server, e.g. by submitting an HTTP request to a REST API. The server then updates the database.

Now you have to get the browser to update, and there are two ways of going about this. One is by polling the server periodically, using AJAX to update parts of the page dynamically without refreshing the whole page. This works, but there's a lot of overhead and it can be a drain on a laptop battery.

The better, but slightly more difficult to setup, alternative is to use [WebSockets.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) WebSockets allow for two-way communication between server and client, and the connection stays open until one party closes it (or it times out after a long time). The client can submit information to or pull information from the server as before, but the server can also push information to the client without the client having to request it. This would typically be how games, chat clients, etc. can operate nearly in real time.

Setting this up isn't necessarily that difficult, but it's a very broad, open-ended topic that's beyond the scope of just iOS development. Beyond the iOS app and the web client, you'll also need a backend that's capable of using sockets. Node.js is a popular JavaScript-based backend for this sort of application; there are numerous others out there as well. You'll have to do your own research to determine what's right for you.